# Countable support iterations of proper forcings with fusion (axiom A), that make $\mathfrak{p}$ large

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Assume we start with a ground model satifying GCH. What are some proper forcing notions with fusion (satisfying axiom A but not countably closed), which when iterated $\aleph_2$ times with countable support, preserve cardinals and make $\mathfrak{p}=\aleph_2$? Does such a forcing even exist?

For example, the prototypical such forcing, if in the above we replace $\mathfrak{p}$ with:

$\mathfrak{b}$, we get Laver forcing,

$\mathfrak{d}$, we get Miller forcing,

$\mathfrak{c}$, we get Sacks forcing, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{p}$? I don't think I've seen that cardinal characteristic before.

Comment: @Noah: It's the cardinal characteristics equals to $\frak t$. :-P

Comment: Are you asking for some sort of definable forcing notion?  Ccc posets all satisfy axiom A with the auxiliary orderings just equality, but it sounded to me like you want something nicely describable like Laver, Miller, and Sacks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber smallest cardinality of the collection of infinite sets that any finite subcollection has infinite intersection but there is no pseudointersection (containment mod finite) for all of them.

Comment: @ToddEisworth I'm not sure if your example works because the auxiliary orderings must refine the original ordering. But yes, I wasn't being precise enough, because for example I don't want countably closed forcings. I wasn't sure how to formalize my requirements; I want the forcing to have a nontrivial fusion property, like the examples mentioned. I left it imprecise sort of on purpose, because I want to see what examples are out there, and if I ad hoc restrict it with some formality, maybe I'll exclude some example in the spirit of the idea that would otherwise help with the understanding.

Comment: @Horse  The Baumgartner survey where Axiom A is introduced has ccc as the first example, so it's OK for the auxiliary orderings to all be equality.

Answer (score 2):

By Bell's theorem, forcing  $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak c$ is the same as forcing Martin's axiom for all $\sigma$-centered forcing notions. So the most natural iteration forcing $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak c$ is an iteration (say: of length $\omega_2$) in which each $\sigma$-centered forcing notion (say: of size $<\aleph_2$) appears as an iterand (cofinally often).

Given your explicit requirement for Axiom A forcing notions, another natural candidate is an iteration in which each axiom A forcing appears as an iterand.

(However, neither of these iterations consists of a single forcing notion repeated $\omega_2$ times.)

Comment: How about iterating the lottery sum of all $\sigma$-centered forcings of size $<\aleph_2$? That would surely be considered iterating "the same forcing", and should probably maybe work.

Comment: Perhaps probably maybe not. The number of such forcings is at least $\aleph_2$, so the direct sum of all these forcings would fail to have the $\aleph_2$-cc.  A CS iteration of length $\omega_1$ of this sum will collapse $\aleph_2$.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case.